# Transfer focus between multiple JFrame's

Tags: java, swing, focus

I'm currently working on additional feature for our application: secondary frame which contains some important additional info for the current context (and some actions). This frame is usually shown on second monitor, so the user can see both of frames. Because keyboard control is very important, I need to transfer focus between the components which are placed in the different frames. Java offers the method `Component#requestFocus()` but don't recommend to use it. I've found another solution

```
public static boolean focusComponent(Component toFocus) {
    Window oldWindow = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getActiveWindow();
    Window newWindow = toFocus instanceof Window ? (Window) toFocus : SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(toFocus);
    if (newWindow != null && newWindow.isVisible() && !newWindow.equals(oldWindow)) {
        // when component placed in a non-active window
        if (newWindow instanceof JFrame) {
            // deiconify frame when required
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) newWindow;
            if ((frame.getExtendedState() & Frame.ICONIFIED) > 0) {
                frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() & ~Frame.ICONIFIED);
            }
        }
        newWindow.toFront();
    }
    return toFocus.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

My question is, what should I use to transfer focus between components placed in the different frames: this solution, `Component#requestFocus()` or something else?